# Tensorflow Object Detection: training from scratch using a .h5 (hdf5) file

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I need to train from scratch a CNN over a COCO dataset with a specific configuration: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/embedded_ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config

Thus, I installed TF Object Detection API and I downloaded the COCO dataset. However the dataset is in .h5 extension.
Is it possible to run the training with this kind of file or do I need to convert it in images in someway? If that is possible, what would the command be?

PS: I was not able to find a pre-trained model with that [config](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/embedded_ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config), this is why I need to train a cnn from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to **convert** the `.hdf5` file to a `.tfrecord` file, you can find examples of how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754968/tensorflow-convert-hdf5-to-tfrecord).